# Is there an efficient way to make this code DRY?

Tags: reactjs

I built out an RPG style character stat screen and had a difficult time keeping this component DRY.

https://github.com/GCJ2/rpg-char-viewer/blob/master/src/mainView/mainView.js

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please, post the code here

Answer (score 0):

The first step to make some code DRY is to identify which parts are repetitive and how you can avoid or reduce these repetitions. 
Please take a look at some examples:

To calculate a particular bonus, you do the following calculation for all the bonuses (line 28 of your GitHub file):

```
const healthBonus =
    equippedGear.weapon.health + equippedGear.armor.health + equippedGear.boots.health +
    equippedGear.headGear.health + equippedGear.cape.health + equippedGear.orb.health;

const attackBonus =
    equippedGear.weapon.attack + equippedGear.armor.attack + equippedGear.boots.attack +
    equippedGear.headGear.attack + equippedGear.cape.attack + equippedGear.orb.attack;
```

Looks like the following logic is used:

```
equippedGear.weapon[name of the bonus] + equippedGear.armor[name of the bonus] + 
equippedGear.boots[name of the bonus] + equippedGear.headGear[name of the bonus] + 
equippedGear.cape[name of the bonus] + equippedGear.orb[name of the bonus]
```

Having the formula, let's create *getBonus* function that allows calculating the particular bonus by passing its name:

```
const getBonus = (name) => equippedGear.weapon[name] + equippedGear.armor[name] +
    equippedGear.boots[name] + equippedGear.headGear[name] + 
    equippedGear.cape[name] + equippedGear.orb[name];
```

Now you can use it:

```
const healthBonus = getBonus('health');
const attackBonus = getBonus('attack');
```

The same refactoring can be done on line 57:

```
const getCharacterStats = (name) => bonuses[name] + 
    gearBonuses[name] + characterBaseStats[name];

const renderedStat = () => {
    setCharacterStats({
      health: getCharacterStats('health'),
      attack: getCharacterStats('attack')
    })
  };
```

Sure, naming is up to you, but you get the idea.

Comment: This was fantastic.
Thank you so much for taking the time to lay this out.

Comment: Glad to help! Could you please upvote and accept my answer (click on the checkmark beside the answer)?

Comment: I did, but my reputation is less than 15 as my account is brand new, so it won't register until my reputation goes up.